# DevExpress XtraTreeList Disable Node Editing

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtratreelist

I want to disable Editing of all nodes of my tree. Any such property apart from a property that allows you to individually set Editing based on cell value ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
foreach(TreeListColumn  col in treeList.Columns)
{
   col.OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = false;
   col.OptionsColumn.ReadOnly = true;
}
```

Comment: Seems to not work in v. 15.2.5 `ReadOnly cannot be set - it's readonly`.

Answer (score 6):

```
treeList.OptionsBehavior.Editable = false;
```

Comment: That still allows me to double click, change value. Only that it comes to old value after refresh.

Comment: Works now in v. 15.2.5, matching first part of question.